# Binding dynamic text with image in one column and Select entier column in datagrid of wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Please let me know how to perform this kind of functionality with WPF `DataGrid`.

And also let use know how to select entire column of a `DataGrid` of WPF. [image]

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? Shouldn't be the impossible to create a `DataTemplate` for such a column.